# Change font in script opt

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this script which tells me how many users are currently on my site, and I'm trying to change the font of the text its pot but I can't seem to figure it out - (pretty new to html you can probably tell)

```
echo <font face="roboto" "  Users Online: <i> $count_user_online </i>"</font>;
```

Full script:

```
    session_start();
$session=session_id();
$time=time();
$time_check=$time-600; 

$host="HIDDEN"; 
$username="HIDDEN"; 
$password="HIDDEN"; 
$db_name="HIDDEN"; 
$tbl_name="HIDDEN";


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to server");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE session='$session'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count=="0"){

$sql1="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(session, time)VALUES('$session', '$time')";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
}

else {
"$sql2=UPDATE $tbl_name SET time='$time' WHERE session = '$session'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
}

$sql3="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);

$count_user_online=mysql_num_rows($result3);

echo "  Users Online: <i> $count_user_online </i>";


$sql4="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE time<$time_check";
$result4=mysql_query($sql4);




mysql_close();
```

Comment: _HTML <font> Tag._ __Not Supported in HTML5__

Comment: Sebastian can u link to the font so that I give you complete code

Answer (score 1):

You aren't closing the Font face tag like so:

```
echo '<font face="roboto"> Users Online: <i>'. $count_user_online .'</i></font>';
```

Please note that the Font tag is not supported in HTML5

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

You would instead as outlined in the comments want to use something like a span. You could then set in-line styles or the more preffered way set it in a style sheet:

```
echo '<span id="yourId"> Users Online: <i>'. $count_user_online .'</i><span>';
```

The style sheet:

```
    #yourId {
       font-face: 'roboto';
    };
```

But if you feel you have to set it in-line

```
echo '<span style="font-face:roboto;"> Users Online: <i>'. $count_user_online .'</i></span>';
```

Comment: May be this: `echo '<font face="roboto">  Users Online: <i>'. $count_user_online .'</i></font>';
`

Comment: You're correct. I forgot to add the quotes so that the variables would come through correctly.

Comment: use <span>, font is depreciated

Answer (score 0):

use this 
Add this to the head tag:

```
   <style> .usersOnline {
    font-family:roboto;
    }
    </style>
```

and then echo this too apply the font face

```
echo "<span class='usersOnline'>   Users Online: <i> $count_user_online </i></span>";
```

You need to import the font in the css between the style tag though.

Comment: How is he suppose to apply the style if he don't out put it? He is not using php shorttags i guess BHAI

Comment: Yeah but I just made it easy, because he is using font tag which means he don't know much about HTML, Though I agree completely with you that style shouldn't be outputted in echo

Comment: Updated it @RayonDabre